# Getting access to filepath with QFileSystemModel

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QFileSystemModel` within a `QListView` that allows me to select items within the file system.

When I select an item, I want to return the filepath in a `QMessageBox`.

So far I have the following code:

```
filemodel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
filemodel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files);
filemodel->setNameFilters(filters);
filemodel->setNameFilterDisables(false);
filemodel->setRootPath(sPath);

//get file path
QString filepath = filemodel->fileName(index);
QMessageBox::information(this, "title", filepath);

ui->listView->setModel(filemodel);
```

This creates the filemodel.

I'm getting this error:

> mainwindow.cpp:46: error: no matching function for call to 'QFileSystemModel::fileName(char* (&)(const char*, int))'

Is this the correct way to go about this? Returning the filepath when an item is selected?

EDIT @dunc123

In constructor:

```
connect(ui->listView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)), this, SLOT(selectedFile(QItemSelection one, QItemSelection two)));
```

selectedFile:

```
void MainWindow::selectedFile(QItemSelection one, QItemSelection two){
    QString file_name = filemodel->fileName(ui->listView->selectionModel()->currentIndex());
    QMessageBox::information(this, "title", file_name);
}
```

It builds and runs but when I click on a file, I get the following error:

```
Object::connect: No such slot MainWindow::selectedFile(QItemSelection one, QItemSelection two) in ../Images/mainwindow.cpp:26
```

Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')

I'm assuming the way I pass the variables is wrong?

Could you help me out?

Comment: Damn, thought you were on to something!

Comment: I am i just need to edit it a little.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer so it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a QModelIndex object to the fileName method of QFileSystemModel.  It appears the symbol "index" is being resolved as a function.  At a guess you have a member function named index in your class.

Edit:
The larger issue here is that you want something to happen when you select an item in your QListView, but you are putting the code to handle this in the constructor.  You need to create a slot in your class and connect this to the signal emitted when an item is selected.

```
connect(ui->listView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &), this, SLOT(...));
```

In this slot you should call the fileName method and display that information.  You'll need to make filemodel a member variable of your class as well so that you can access it from the slot.

Edit 2:
The way you are specifying your slot when calling `connect` is incorrect, it should be:

```
connect(ui->listView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)), this, SLOT(selectedFile(QItemSelection , QItemSelection)));
```

However, since you aren't using either of those parameters in your slot, you can infact remove them all together from your slot, e.g. define it in your header as:

```
void selectedFile();
```

And connect it using:

```
connect(ui->listView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)), this, SLOT(selectedFile()));
```

QT will work out that you don't want either of the parameters from the signal.

Comment: And this QModelIndex will contain the data for the currently selected file?

Comment: I've edited my question with my updated code, I think I'm almost there now!

Comment: YES!!! Thankyou ever so much for your help. I just need to think about it a bit more to see the patterns and learn from it. Thanks @dunc123

Comment: Glad to hear its working.  You might want to read [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) for more information on signals and slots in Qt.

Comment: I understand what the documentation is saying but I get a little confused with laying out all the code and where it goes. It's my first attempt at C++ or QT/ C++ and I'm still trying to get used to where the code goes, accessing it, pointers etc.

Comment: Learning how to structure code is the hard part and something you only really learn with practice.  Good luck and keep at it!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of selected indexes with [QItemSelectionModel::selectedIndexes()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedIndexes) function.

Heres an example of how you can use it:

```
QModelIndexList list = ui->listView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
foreach (QModelIndex index, list)
{
    QString file_name = fileModel->fileName(index);            
}
```

Or if you can only select a single item, you can use the [QItemSelectionModel::currentIndex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentIndex) function like this:

```
QString file_name = fileMode->fileName(ui->listView->selectionModel()->currentIndex());
```

You can also connect the [QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) signal to a slot and use that in similar fashion. `QListView` has a [selectionModel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) function that you can use to retrieve a `QItemSelectionModel` object. `QItemSelection` has a [indexes()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qitemselection.html#indexes) function that returns a `QModelIndexList`.

Comment: Using your first example, I get the following error: /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Headers/qlistview.h:180: error: 'virtual QModelIndexList QListView::selectedIndexes() const' is protected .. any ideas? I'll look at the second possibility now.

Comment: did that need to have () on the end of currentIndex? I'm trying to work out where this code should be so it executes after the application starts.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used a combination of this with @dunc123's answer. The currentindex was the one! The documentation is so deep!

Comment: @Luke Oh yes, sorry about that. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
QString filepath = filemodel->fileName(index);

mainwindow.cpp:46: error: no matching function for call to 'QFileSystemModel::fileName(char* (&)(const char*, int))'
```

Looks like "index" is a function, not a QModelIndex...

You can use a slot that is connected to the model's signal "currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)" to get the new selected index.